# How to connect to composer dag folder from GCP Cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-composer

I'm new to GCP. going over different documents on gcp composer and cloud shell but not able to find a place where I can connect the cloud shell environment to the composer DAG folder.

Right now, I'm creating python script outside cloud shell (local system), uploading manually to DAG folder but i want to do this on the cloud shell only. can any one give me the directions on it?

Also when I tried to use import airflow in my python file on cloud shell it gives me error that module not found. how do I install that too?

Answer (score 1):

Take alook on this GCP documentation:

[Adding and Updating DAGs (workflows)](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags)

among many other entries, you will find information like this one:

**Determining the storage bucket name**
To determine the name of the storage bucket associated with your environment:

```
gcloud composer environments describe ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
  --location LOCATION \
  --format="get(config.dagGcsPrefix)"
```

where:

`ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is the name of the environment.
`LOCATION` is the Compute Engine region where the environment is located.
`--format` is an option to specify only the dagGcsPrefix property instead of all environment details.
The dagGcsPrefix property shows the bucket name:

gs://region-environment_name-random_id-bucket/

**Adding or updating a DAG**
To add or update a DAG, move the Python .py file for the DAG to the environment's dags folder in Cloud Storage.

```
gcloud composer environments storage dags import \
    --environment ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location LOCATION \
    --source LOCAL_FILE_TO_UPLOAD
```

where:

`ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is the name of the environment.
`LOCATION` is the Compute Engine region where the environment is located.
`LOCAL_FILE_TO_UPLOAD` is the DAG to upload.